# Visualize and solve $\int\int_D e^{y^2}dxdy$ with $D=\{x\geq 0$ , $x\leq y\leq 1\}$

Tags: integration

I want to teach the solution of this problem. My plan is to show the visual representation to show the relationship of the function to its visual representation for better understanding. Here is the problem:

$\int\int_D e^{y^2}\,dx\,dy$ with $D=\{x\geq 0$ , $x\leq y\leq 1\}.$

I tried to express the given to

$\int_0^1\int_x^1 e^{y^2}\,dx\,dy$.

I know that I need to change the order of integration. This is where I am stuck up.

I tried another solution:

$\int_0^1\int_x^1e^{y^2}\,dx\,dy$

= $\int_0^1 x e^{y^2}\|_{x=y}^{x=1}dy$

= $\int_0^1 (1-y)e^{y^2}dy$

= $\int_0^1 e^{y^2}dy$ $-$ $\int_0^1 ye^{y^2}dy$

= $\frac{\sqrt{π}}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{2e^{y^2}}{\sqrt{π}}dy$ $-$ $\int_0^1 ye^{y^2}dy$.     Given that: $\int \frac{2e^{y^2}}{\sqrt{π}}dy$ = $erfi(y)$,

a special integral (imaginary error function), we have:

= $\frac{\sqrt{π}}{2}erfi(y)|_{y=0}^{y=1}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 2ye^{y^2}dy$

=$\frac{\sqrt{π}}{2}erfi(y)|_{y=0}^{y=1}$ $-$ $\frac{e-1}{2}$

Is this okay? What part of the solution needs change or improvement? If there's any,why?

Comment: I am sure your limits here are dy first then dx.

$\int_{0}^1 \int_{x}^1 e^{y^2}dydx$.

You can change this to:

$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^y e^{y^2}dxdy$.
By noting that $0\leq x \leq y <1$

Comment: Hi George! Based on the given material, it is $dx$ first before $dy$.

Comment: Thank you for editing Thomas! That is my question. How it should be switched?

Comment: Also, what does it look like in a 3d graph? Can you recommend any application that I can use to model the double integral problem.

Comment: Sure you can have $dx$ first (see my second expression), however what it appears to say is $x  \leq x \leq 1$!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The integration is over the shaded area in the diagram. So, change the order of the as follows,

$$\int_0^1dx \int_x^1 e^{y^2}dy = \int_0^1dye^{y^2}\int_0^ydx=\int_0^1e^{y^2}ydy=\frac{e-1}2$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes you indeed need to change the order of integration. Notice that we cannot integrate $e^{y^2}$. It would be really nice if there was an extra $y$, we could then use a $u$-sub. This is where changing the order of integration works nicely and helps us out.

We have $0\leq y \leq 1$ and $x\leq y \leq 1$. After making a quick picture of this domain we see that actually the region can be described by $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0\leq x\leq y$. We thus obtain : $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int^1_x e^{y^2} dydx = \int^1_0 \int^y_0 e^{y^2} dxdy= \int^1_0 e^{y^2} \left(\int^y_0 dx\right)dy=\int^1_0 ye^{y^2} dy$. Now you can finish using a $u$-sub.